# Multiple Spinner items position

Tags: android

How can i get multiple selected spinners items position?
I am trying to make a converter which have 3 Spinners first one select category, second one From and another is To.After selecting first Spinner second and third Spinner will be auto generate. i want to know how can i get selected spinners position for above three spinners?

i have wrote this for first spinners

```
 OnItemSelectedListener listener = new OnItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,
            long id) {
        switch (position) {
        case 0: {
                              //I want here second and third spinners position
                             }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think if this is possible using default Spinner as the [Spinners guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html) says,

**Spinners provide a quick way to select *one* value from a set.**

You will have to create a custom drop down list for this. [An example.](http://asnehal.wordpress.com/2012/04/03/multi-select-drop-down-list-in-android/)

A MultiSelectSpinner is also available on [Github](https://github.com/wongk/MultiSelectSpinner) for use.